# Can I find quantum circuit drawing of BB84 protocol somewhere

Tags: quantum-information

Quantum algorithms and protocols are often expressed as circuit diagrams. But I have not been able to find the circuit diagram of BB84 protocol. Has anyone seen one?

Comment: There isn't a lot going on in that protocol at the Quantum gates level, so I'm not sure you can find what you're looking for. You're basically moving qubits around and measuring them. The essence is the protocol itself which is choosing what to do with the measured values *after* the measurement is done. Also note a significant portion of the protocol is meant to be executed on a *classical* channel (the final part where one party discloses the bases used in measuring the qubits)

Answer (score 1):

BB84 is good for teaching although it may not be the most practical or efficient quantum key distribution protocol. I have come up with my own way including a circuit diagram to explain the quantum channel of the protocol and don't know whether the approach has been tried by others. I also hope to find out whether it is indeed acceptable by others. In the circuit diagram, Alice' data bit turns the qubit to |0> or |1> (the Z gate). Then, a H gate is applied if the key bit is "1" and turns |0> -> |+> and |1> -> |->. I can use a constellation diagram, with which electrical engineering students are familiar, to show that the resulting state corresponds exactly to the concatenation "key bit"+"data bit". The H gate applies a 45 degree rotation of the "0" or "1" vector. If Bob's key bit is "1", another H gate is applied and results in rotating the state vector 45 degrees. If the Alice and Bob's keys agree, Bob successfully gets the data bit.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how the [Pauli $Z$ gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Pauli_gates_(X,Y,Z)), being unary, is taking two inputs in your diagram. In particular it leaves the qubit state $|0\rangle$ unchanged... the rest of the diagram is quite unclear as well but that's just immediately apparent. I think this diagram doesn't carry a lot of information about the protocol on its own, and may only confuse someone that's trying to decode it. As an aside, BB84 is a protocol for key agreement, and you seem to be somehow including within it data transmission as well...

Comment: I understand that I assume a lot being known and have left a lot unexplained. The single lines are quantum channels and the double lines are classical channels. The dots are control gates. Therefore, it's a control-Z gate, which applies Z operation depending on the data bit. I'm writing a book explaining quantum information to EE and CS students. and am explaining things in their languages. To CS students, BB84 is a quantum adaptation of the classical one-time-pad (OTP) encryption protocol. And the data bits and key bits refer to those in the OTP protocol.

Comment: Because half of the data output bits are not good, BB84 cannot be used for encryption as OTP intends to. The "good" data output bits can only be used as key bits for conventional symmetric key encryption, OTP or something else. In addition, "encoding" and "constellation diagrams" belong to EE domain and are probably foreign to physicists.

Comment: Okay. Of course you can explain everything in the text. But just note that even in CS one usually doesn't mix a circuit diagram with a protocol diagram. [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Diffie-Hellman-Schl%C3%BCsselaustausch.svg/1200px-Diffie-Hellman-Schl%C3%BCsselaustausch.svg.png) is a typical example of a protocol diagram. I think it is much clearer that way, because with a protocol you have to be able to clearly see the messages exchanged and the order of operations. I think that embedding it into the circuit diagram can create a lot of confusion.

Comment: The critical step in the BB84 protocol is to replace the XOR operation in OTP with quantum operations. There are many ways to describe a protocol. And there are plenty of references explaining OTP. I believe it's been established that circuit diagrams are best or better ways to describe quantum operations.

Comment: No.. the XOR is the encryption/decryption operation in OTP. The significant change in BB84 is how you agree on a shared secret key. In OTP it is not specified at all! In OTP it is an assumption that the two parties already share such a key.

Comment: We are circling back: BB84 is an adaptation of OTP in principle for key distribution although it's not the original OTP. There are plenty of references that explain well the rest of the protocol, including the part that Alice-Bob exchange over the classical channel. The difficult part is the quantum operations that replace the XOR. Do you find a better way than a circuit diagram to describe the quantum operations?

Comment: I find it's worthwhile to discuss the quantum operations in BB84, which is the most difficult part for CS and EE students. To discuss the non-quantum portion of BB84, I'd recommend a separate thread.

Comment: OTP is *not* a key agreement protocol. BB84 *is* one. You can't compare the two at all.